# Is it possible to publish the build project itself of a project using sbt?

Tags: scala, build, sbt

I have a downstream project which would like to reference values defined inside the build files of an upstream project. I was thinking if there is an easy way to publish a jar with the source files of the build project itself then I could publish the build project of the upstream project and the build project of the downstream repo could depend on the build project of the upstream repo. Is it possible to do this? Is it reasonable? Are there other, potentially better solutions?

To be clear because I can see how the above might be confusing (and pardon me if I am using incorrect terminology), I am referring to the recursive nature of sbt builds and the fact that the build definition for a project is a project in itself and that's what I would like to publish, not the source files of the project itself.

I'm familiar with writing [plugins in sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Plugins.html) and with the [sbt buildinfo plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo).  I'm hoping there's another way.

Comment: publishing locally will not do the work? look at http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.4/docs/Detailed-Topics/Publishing.html#publishing-locally

Comment: Oh I think I understand now, you mean about using project/target built files something like that